# trouble to update or edit the json file using php

Tags: php, javascript, json, jsonp, jquery-callback

**index.json**

`myjsoncallback([{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Chai","UnitPrice":18,"UnitsInStock":39,"Discontinued":false}])`

**Php Code :**

```
$string = file_get_contents("../index.json");

$string = utf8_encode($string);

$json_data = json_decode($string, true);

echo $json_data;

$i=count($json_data);

$json_data[$i] = array('ProductID'=>$fileName,'ProductName'=>$name,'ptext'=>$message,'Discontinued'=>false);

$fp = fopen('../index.json', 'a');

fwrite($fp, json_encode($json_data));

fclose($fp);
```

I want to write data in jsone file with jsonpcallback.

Comment: why you are using utf8_encode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `json_decode()` if your file contains JSONP data. If you want to handle JSON data with PHP you have to remove the callback form JSONP and just encode/decode JSON objects.

Comment: That's a different question, tho. You still can't use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` with JSONP data. You have to remove the callback to handle that kind of data with PHP